# while running command Heroku logs Errros are below

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku

I am trying to push my app on heroku to go live then getting this error:

```
2018-02-15T18:19:55.377507+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=shoppingwave.herokuapp.com
request_id=551a7986-4cd6-4b43-9b9a-9f1eb46a5bc4 fwd="157.50.221.99"
dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Please explain what you are doing to receive the error. Also post some more information from your code

Comment: i am trying to push my app on heroku to go live then getting this error

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem with your `STATIC_ROOT` setting: it's set to a tuple rather than a string.

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'live-static-files', "static-root"),
STATICFILES_DIRS = (

    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static-storage'),
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'live-static-files', 'media-root'),
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',

)

Comment: You have a comma at the end of your STATIC_ROOT setting which should not be there.